# Переименовать файлы в папке по порядку

Tags: windows, bat

Нужно с помощью BAT файла, сделать так что при его запуске в папке, все файлы    определенного расширения(например .jpg) переименовывались по порядку,             от 1 до того числа сколько их находится в папке.
    'К примеру имеется такие файлы:
     daisdasgbdaso.jpg
     hudsghaiudgag.jpg
     dhsadhkajshdk.jpg
    А нужно на выходе  1.jpg
                       2.jpg
                       3.jpg'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать [следующим образом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863483/command-prompt-batch-rename-multiple-files-with-sequential-numbering):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set num=100
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /B *.jpg') do (
   set /A num+=1
   ren "%%i" "!num:~1!.jpg"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Вот моё решение похожей проблемы.**
Расположение:

> .bat файл лежит рядом с папкой (Result — имя папки).
> В папке те файлы которые нужно переименовать.
> В моём случае это были .jpg файлы с разными именами...
> Этот .bat файл переименует их вот в такие файлы file-000.jpg, file-001.jpg, file-002.jpg

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd /d Result
set "count=1000"
set a="*.jpg"
for /f "usebackq delims=*" %%f in (`dir /b /o:-d /tc %a%`) do (ren "%%f" file-!count:~1!.jpg
set /a count+=1
)
pause
```

**SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion** Раскрытие переменных через знаки (!)
**cd /d Result** заходим в папку Result
**set "count=1000"** переменная в которой я обозначил количество нулей *file-001.jpg*
**set a="*.jpg"** переменная обозначает какие файлы ищем.

*(`dir /b /o:-d /tc %a%`)*
**dir** - Позволяет отобразить список файлов и подкаталогов. Далее сортируем. 
**/b** - Вывод только имен файлов.
**/o:-d** - Сортировка списка отображаемых файлов в обратном порядке ( от новых к старым ).
**/tc** - Сортировать по времени создания файла.
**%a%** - Вызываем переменную.

**usebackq** Задает возможность использования кавычек для имен файлов *Такие вот>* **"**.
Задает исполнение строки, заключенной в обратные кавычки, как команды*Такие вот>* **`**,
а строки в одиночных кавычках — как команды в символьной строке*Такие вот>* **'**.

**delims=xxx** Задает набор разделителей. Заменяет набор разделителей по умолчанию, состоящий из пробела и символа табуляции.